# MercadoPago Django-Python

Tags: python, django, mercadopago

Hace días que tengo inconveniente para integrar mercadopago a mi proyecto Django-Python, estoy intentando agregar el back_urls y me da este error: `(Reverse for 'pago_exitoso' not found. 'pago_exitoso' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)`

```
url.py:
 path('pago-exitoso/', pago_exitoso, name="pago_exitoso"), 

view.py:

 def mercadopago_checkout(request, **kwargs):

    mp = mercadopago.MP("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    user = request.user
    articulo_orden = ArticuloOrden.objects.filter(usuario=user, finalizado=False)
    items=[]
    for item in articulo_orden:

        nomProducto = item.articulos.nombre.nombre
        cantProducto = item.cantidad
        if item.articulos.precio_descuento:
            precProducto = item.articulos.precio_descuento
        else:
            precProducto = item.articulos.precio       
        monArt = 'ARS'
        datos = {'title':nomProducto, 'quantity':cantProducto, 'currency_id':monArt, 'unit_price':precProducto}
        items.append(datos)

    preference = {
                "items":items,

                "back_urls": [
                                {
                                    "success":reverse('pago_exitoso')                                    
                                },
                            ],

                "auto_return": "approved",
            }    

    preferenceResult = mp.create_preference(preference)
    url_forward = preferenceResult['response']['init_point']
    print(preferenceResult)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url_forward)
```

Espero ayuden soy nuevo en esto.

Saludso

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás direccionando la URL a la View correspondiente.

```
path('pago-exitoso/', pago_exitoso, name="pago_exitoso"),
```

Debería ser así:

```
path('pago-exitoso/', views.mercadopago_checkout, name="pago_exitoso"),
```

Espero que ayude.